# Cautious File Writer

Tags: beginner, ruby, file, tdd

I'm trying to follow the path of Sandi Metz and others who state that aiming for small and simple is good for writing understandable code. I've written a method that takes care of writing content to a file without overwriting any existing file of the same name. I wrote it TDD style and, once the tests passed, I refactored the rather large methods into smaller methods, hoping that it would improve readability.

I hope you can tell me whether I succeeded, or how I could further improve on my code. I've considered adding modules (such as a "Appender" module) to my class in order to improve the code according to the single responsibility principle, but can't figure out whether it would actually clarify things more, or whether the added lines would make the intended  clarification void.

```
class CautiousWriter
  def self.write(filename, content)
    if File.exists?(filename) 
      rename_existing_file_beginning_with(filename)
    end
    create_file(filename, content)
  end

  private

  def self.rename_existing_file_beginning_with(filename)
    if File.exists? append_old_to(filename)
      rename_with_old_and_number_appended(filename)
    else
      rename_with_old_appended(filename)
    end
  end

  def self.rename_with_old_and_number_appended(filename)
    old_and_num_appended = find_available_filename(filename)
    rename(filename, old_and_num_appended)
  end

  def self.find_available_filename(filename)
    number = 0
    until File.exists?(append_old_to(filename) + number.to_s) == false
      number += 1
    end
    append_old_to(filename) + number.to_s
  end

  def self.rename_with_old_appended(filename)
    rename(filename, append_old_to(filename))
  end

  def self.rename(filename, new_filename)
    File.rename(filename, new_filename)
  end

  def self.create_file(filename, content)
    File.open(filename, 'w') { |file| file.write(content) }
  end

  def self.append_old_to(filename)
    filename + '_old'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Before looking at the code, I have a comment on the overall functionality of it. The idea is nice, but it commits a cardinal sin: *It messes with files that do not belong to it.*

This is A Very Bad Idea™.

Say you want to write the file "log.txt", but it already exists. Your code will rename the existing file, but that file may be in use. Some other process might expect it to be there, and fail when it gets renamed. Or *your* process will fail if the existing file is owned by another user or is locked. Or the other process will just start overwriting *your* file, since, hey, that's the one with the correct name. Or you get weird race conditions where you rename a file, and immediately after that, another process - finding the file gone - creates a new one, after which you overwrite the other process' new file; exactly what you're trying *not* to do. (see [user50399's answer for more](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60261/14370))

In other words, I wouldn't use this, regardless of the code itself.

But speaking of code, let's look at that.

You've certainly been diligent in dividing everything into methods - kudos. But, [as ckuhn203 notes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60260/14370), a method with `and` in it indicates that the method is in fact doing several things.

I have to wonder why you're using a two-stage method of resolving file name conflicts: One is to append "_old", and the other is to also append a number. Just appending "_old" may not be enough, whereas numbers can simply increment forever (more or less). So you have one way of renaming that may or may not work, and one which will always work. So why use both? It just complicates the code.

Besides, maybe you don't want "_old" in the filename. Maybe you want "-backup" or just nothing. Right now the string is hard coded in a method body, so it's not exactly configurable.

I don't see any handling of file extensions, or anything to indicate that it's been considered. Though not required, it could be nice to rename "file.txt" to "file_old4.txt" instead of "file.txt_old4". Especially since you're using an underscore, meaning that the renamed file's extension is suddenly ".txt_old4", which isn't a real extension.
*However,* dealing with file extensions is a huge hassle, so if you look at something like the `logrotate` *nix utility, it just appends a dot and a number, instead of trying to parse file extensions, so you get files like "log.txt.3". Note that it's *not* using an underscore; it's simply adding an entirely new extension that's all-numeric. While not perfect, it's less likely to confuse anyone.

There's also the question of why this is a class. All its methods are class methods, and it has no state. Yet making it a class implies you can instantiate it - but that doesn't really do anything. You basically just get an instance of `Object` with no discernible functionality. I'd probably prefer to write it as a module instead ([here are a number of ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834567/167996)).

On a micro-level, I noticed this:

```
until File.exists?(append_old_to(filename) + number.to_s) == false
```

Saying "until something's not true" is the same as just saying "*while* something's true". It's cool that Ruby has the `until` keyword, but in this case you want a good old-fashioned `while` loop.
You could also avoid calling `append_old_to` again and again, since its return value isn't going to change. And personally, I'd use string interpolation here

```
number = 0
base_filename = append_old_to(filename)
while File.exists?("#{base_filename}#{number}")
  ...
```

Incidentally, this single method may be the most useful, if you "flip it" to produce a *new* filename you can use instead. I.e. don't try to rename existing files: Make sure that *you* have a non-conflicting filename before you write anything. Again, there's a risk of race conditions, if you get the file name before writing, but it's less risky than renaming existing files.

You might simply monkey patch the `IO` class with an `open_uniq` (or some such) method, which you pass the usual name, mode and block, but which - instead of returning the number of bytes written - returns whatever filename it *actually* ended up writing. So you give it "log.txt" and some data to write, and it might return "log.4.txt" because there happened to be a few of log*.txt files already.

Comment: Point taken with ownership of files. I think I will do general rewrite to turn the functionality of the class on its head. Is there a general strategy to ensure against collision between processes when manipulating files? This was exactly what I was trying to achieve with my code, by the way :) So I want to approach that feature again, but in a more proper way.

Comment: Also, I had my doubts about the [filename]_old[number] strategy, rather than the simpler [filename][number]. I kind of wanted the "backup" filenames to give an impression of their purpose with the "_old" part. I think I've changed my mind now, and will go for [filename][number] in the next iteration. Also, whoops on the extension thing! Hadn't thought of that. Cheers for the "log.txt.3" tip, I think I'll see if that works out!

Comment: I'd thought about making the class a module myself, and now I feel more certain that it's the right way to go. I have a Java background and feel a little uncertain about the general purpose of modules. Thank you!

Comment: @Reefersleep Glad it helped! As for avoiding collisions in the file system, [user50399's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60261/14370) points out the flags you can set. An exclusive lock will make the file system complain if you can't get such a lock (or it'll complain to other processes if they try to access the file you've gotten a lock on)

Comment: I'm against double negations myself because they confuse me, so the "until == false" bit is a brainfart. Calling "append_old_to" again and again might seem dumb from a resource perspective, but I'm generally trying to do things more functionally. Whenever you introduce a variable, you introduce a lifescope that you have to keep in your head when reading the code. If you can avoid this, you save your headspace for more important stuff. I'm inspired by the more functional Clojure, which I'm also learning, and I might be in the wrong when trying to write functional Ruby.

Comment: Is using string interpolation considered more readable/idiomatic in the Ruby community than simple +'ing?

Comment: @Reefersleep Fair point about `append_old_to`. In a class, you would perhaps be better served with an argument-less `suffixed_filename` method that simply _is_ filename + "old" (or whatever). It's still a method call, but it looks a little nicer in the context where it's used. But it's a question of taste, I admit. As for string interpolations, yes, I would consider that more idomatic than `+`. It makes it absolutely explicit that you're dealing with a string, rather than, say, two arrays (for which `+` means concat) or dates or anything else with a `+` method.

Comment: Cheers! When talking about `suffixed_filename` being argument-less, do you mean something like

Comment: Cheers! When talking about `suffixed_filename` being argument-less, do you mean something like `def suffixed_filename "#{@filename}_old" end` ?
Where the filename had already been set as a part of the instance state? I definitely agree that it would look nicer when called, but it grinds against my functional desires :D

Comment: @Reefersleep Yes, that's what I was thinking, and yeah, it's hard to do it "right". Still, here the return value is basically constant, so you can treat `suffixed_filename` as basically a lazily evaluated variable. Doens't work for a module-based solution, of course. But in any case, if you're skipping the suffixing in favor of just numbering, the whole discussion is moot :)

Answer (score 3):

This code suffers from Time-of-check vs. Time-of-use problems. Even if you check that the file you intend to create doesn't exist, some other process might create the file in the split-second between the check and the file operation. In some cases, these kinds of bugs might even be considered security vulnerabilities.

Instead of (or in addition to) checking beforehand, check the return values to see whether an operation succeeded. Set flags on `File.open()`, for example, to `CREAT | EXCL` to ensure that it will never open an existing file.

Comment: Cheers, I'll redesign the class as per your and @Flambino 's suggestions in order to avoid file access collisions :)

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your methods may be trying to do a little too much. For example:

> ```
> def self.rename_with_old_and_number_appended(filename)
> ```

And

> ```
> def self.rename_with_old_appended(filename)
> ```

1. Seeing the word "and" in a method name is always a red flag.
2. Neither of these seem to be actually related to writing files.

I imagine that you take these actions often, so you (correctly) created methods for them. The problem is they don't really belong to a file writer and shouldn't be part of the API. They belong in the client code. When you go to reuse `CautiousWriter` in a different project, you'll find that you need different methods, perhaps with similar functionality. After several iterations of this, you'll end up with "one class to rule them all" and it will be an ummaintainable jungle of code.

Write a new class that inherits from `CautiousWriter` to implement these functions.

Comment: I think that those methods are intended to be atomic operations.

Comment: Yes @user50399, I believe so, but that doesn't change my advice.

Comment: Cheers for the advice, @RubberDuck. I get your point about "and", and I'm trying to follow it generally in my code from here on out :) I'm not sure I agree with the second point, though - the whole idea with `CautiousWriter` was to ensure that old files with the same name were not overwritten. I do see that this is not in congruence with the class name. Following the other advice further up, I'm going to redesign the class so that it leaves existing files be and instead finds an available [filename][number] name and writes the file to that. Do you think that would work better?

Comment: A FileWriter in my mind doesn't fuss around with specific names when it renames. It simply renames it to whatever you pass to it. I still recommend a base class. It's been my experience with Ruby that very few classes should be more than a single screen or two.

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other regarding levels of abstraction. Think of my class as the client code you're talking about. The lower level of abstraction that you think belongs to CautiousWriter already exists in File. CautiousWriter serves the purpose for me to simply aim a desired filename and content at, and ensure that a) no existing files are overwritten and b) my file is saved. I don't think that this is too complex for one class. I completely agree with  you about class size, and my class takes up exactly one screen on my end :)

Comment: And I've been scared off from unnecessary inheritance from working with complex inheritance trees with huge public APIs in Java :o